# How to Access a vue data from jquery on click event handler

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a vue component as

```
var app_3 = new Vue({
    el:'#app-3',
    data() {
        return {
            step:1,
            models:''
        }
    }
});
```

And I am handling a click event using
jquery like

```
$('body').on('click', '.models', function() {
});
```

I would like to access the vue data **models** from the jquery event handler.
How can I access it?

Comment: Can you please add more script and explain why do you want to access vue stuff in jquery?

Comment: You're almost 100% doing it wrong. Let Vue handle the click, not jQuery.

Comment: Agreed it's probably not the best way to do things. But you could save your root instance to a global window variable, like this person has: https://www.rent-a-hero.de/wp/2017/08/25/how-to-call-methods-of-a-vuejs-app-from-outside/

Comment: It better would be to add the handler from within vue, probably from within the `mounted` lifecycle hook

Comment: @JamesWesc Why would he not simply add a `v-on:click` directive to his `.models` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know your purpose but you can use `app_3.step` to get and set vue data.

```js
var app_3 = new Vue({
    el:'#app-3',
    data() {
        return {
            step:1,
            models:''
        }
    }
});

$('body').on('click', '.models', function() {
app_3.step +=1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="app-3">
  Step : {{step}}
</div>
<button class="models">Models</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This works, but it is not the best way. See connexo's answer for the correct way to handle events in Vue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mangle jQuery and Vue together. For event handling Vue has all the tools necessary.

```js
var app_3 = new Vue({
    el:'#app-3',
    data() {
        return {
            step: 1,
            models:''
        }
    },
    methods: {
      decreaseStep() {
        this.step -= 1
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-3">
  Step : {{step}}
  <button @click="step+=1">+</button>
  <button @click="decreaseStep">-</button>
</div>
```

These are just two simple examples. You'd go with the +-button code if the task is so trivial, otherwise you'd create a `function` inside the `methods` object on your viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

On Vue Js i create a method and called it in before Mount:

```
 var app_3 = new Vue({
        el:'#app-3',
        data() {
            return {
                step:1,
                models:''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            // called by beforeMount()
            foo() {
                let proxy = this
                $('body').on('click', '.models', function() {
                    // call a method
                    proxy.bar()
                    // set a variable data
                    proxy.step = 2
                });
            },
            // called each .model click
            bar(){
                console.log('it id working');
            }
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.foo()
        }
    })
```